# How is the Ventura Share menu different from prior versions of the share menu on OSX?

Tags: macos, sharing, beta, ventura

The Ventura share menu seems to have made a number of changes.  It maybe is using a better Extension architecture?  But the UX seems different.

This pertains to Venture 13.0 Beta (22A5321d), but the difference between 13.x builds has been small or zero.

Is there a clear list of the differences between Venture and 12.x (Monterrey)?

Comment: It is a beta - the issues might mean it will change - so this is not answerable

Comment: but it doesn't always, and with some digging I could probably cite a few cases of that — at least one with the share menu, that had odd UX throughout one or more OS versions.   I think that a good answer to this question can raise visibility for such issues in a way that supports Apple's internal prioritization, and their teams' thinking generally

Comment: I support any question where a specific build is asked about. Whether things change or not past that build is easy to manage with answers and edits to them as needed without us needing to guess the future.  +1 in my book. I personally will not answer this question until Ventura ships, but not everyone reads the NDA the same and some people may be willing to comment before general release.

Comment: *There is no clear list anywhere.* Apple doesn't make lists for every changes in each single feature at each update. The only thing I could advise you to do is to compare [Use the share menu on Mac - Ventura](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40614/13.0/mac/13.0) with [Use the share menu on Mac - Monterey](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40614/12.0/mac/12.0).